# Populate field in a form depending on value on another from database in SP2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, sql-server

I have a List with three fields, all three text boxes. The first field is an ID, which when populated needs to trigger a DB query to pull corresponding title and description from a table in SQL Server 2008 DB. In case the first field changes, other two needs to be refreshed. I have very little background in SP, but I'm pretty good with C# and SQL. It'd be great if you could point me to some kind of a tutorial to do this.

Thanks!
Ro

Answer (score 0):

try to get the data from SQL to the [External list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558778(v=office.14).aspx) in SharePoint. 
Then you can query this list like any other in SharePoint using JavaScript - client side code.

I am using [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) library to help me with the queries, check the method [GetListItems](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wiki/search?tab=Home&SearchText=getlistitems).

Hiding and filling the fields is then just matter of few lines of JS using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Luccio! I will try that out and let you know if it helped :)

Comment: Apparently, the business data connectivity services required for this is not available on the SP server, and I have no access to it. Is there any other way to use a data connection from which I can pull data?

Comment: Try to contact admin to activate the feature. Otherwise, you will have to create your own WS and call it by JS inside SP.

Comment: I see. Do you think it is a viable optio for me to create a webpart using VS2012 independently and add it in my sharepoint?

Comment: It depends how complex will be your solution. I would prefer JS solution because it is displaying data, no need to access lists with elevated privileges, etc. JS is also better for the future - in SP2013 full-trust solutions are not recommended. Also you can change your JS solution w/o deployment - just modify the web part in your browser. You will need some JS either way, because you want to display/hide info based on user selection, so why not do the whole solution with JS. Using the libraries mentioned above it is not that hard.